# simple login C# and MySQL web application

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, web-applications, authentication

I Have a few bugs in my code, for some reason when I try to catch at the end it throws up errors saying it is missing lots of brackets although I don't think it is.
could some one please let me know where I have gone wrong.

**Code:**

```
namespace login
{
   public partial class _Default : Page
   {
      // decleration of tabels and dataadapters including my connection string for my MySQL databse
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      MySqlConnection cs = new MySqlConnection(@"SERVER= ********;username=******;password=******;Allow Zero Datetime=true; Initial Catalog = benoatsc_GreenFilm");

      MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      String totalDonations = string.Empty;

      protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         try
         {
            MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from films.user where user_name='" + this.username.Text + "; and password='" + this.password.Text + "';", cs);
            MySqlDataReader myreader;
            cs.Open();
            myreader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();

            int count = 0;
            while (myreader.Read())
            {
               count = count + 1;
            }

            if (count == 1)
            {
               Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('wow your in !!');</script>");
            }

            else if (count > 1)
            {
               Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('duplicate');</script>");
            }

            else Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('wrong password');</script>");

            cs.Close();
         }

         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert(ex.message);</script>");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Off topic:  You should use SQL Parameters.  As it is, you are vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: try entering `' or '1'='1` in username, once your code is working see [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: thank you I will include preventions for MySQL injections

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Problem 1:** you have opened extra  curley brace `{` after `try block`.
**Problem 2:** you have opened `user_name` parameter with `single quotes` but you have not closed with `single quotes`.

**Solution 1:** you need to remove extra curley brace opened after try block.
**Solution 2:** you need to enclose `user_name` parameter with `single quotes` properly.

**Suggestion :** your query is open to `SQL Injection attacks`, i would suggest to use `parameterised queries` to avoid this.

**Complete Code:** using `parameterised queries`

```
namespace login
{
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    // decleration of tabels and dataadapters including my connection string for my MySQL databse
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    MySqlConnection cs = new MySqlConnection(@"SERVER= ********;username=******;password=******;Allow Zero Datetime=true; Initial Catalog = benoatsc_GreenFilm");

    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    String totalDonations = string.Empty;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

                MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from films.user where user_name=@username and password=@password;", cs);
                MySqlDataReader myreader;
                SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",this.username.Text);
                SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password",this.password.Text);
                cs.Open();

                myreader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();

                int count = 0;
                while (myreader.Read())
                {
                    count = count + 1;
                }

                if (count == 1)
                {
                    Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('wow your in !!');</script>");
                }

                else if (count > 1)
                {
                    Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('duplicate');</script>");
                }

                else Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('wrong password');</script>");

                cs.Close();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                 Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert(ex.message);</script>");
                 }//end of catch block

        }//end of try block
    }//end of class 
}//end of namespace
```

Comment: Excelent @Sudhakar Tillapudi, thank you. one problem though when using parametrised queries the error comes up that I may be missing a reference for this, would you know what reference that would be ?

Comment: Ahh was my faults namespace was different. thank you as always @Sudhakar Tillapudi once again you have been very helpful.

Comment: @Beep: You are Welcome :) , I'm gald tobe help of you again :) have a nice day.

Comment: you could also used SelectCommand.ExecuteScalar(); instead of SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();

Answer (score 2):

Apart from missing brackets and wrong SQL query *(contains semicolon)* you can improve your code a lot. You can use `ExecuteScalar` and modify your query to `COUNT(*)`. That way you don't have to count in your code. Also use [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) statement which will ensure the connection to be closed even in case of an exception. So your code should be on the following linesL

```
namespace login
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        // decleration of tabels and dataadapters including my connection string for my MySQL databse
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        MySqlConnection cs = new MySqlConnection(@"SERVER= ********;username=******;password=******;Allow Zero Datetime=true; Initial Catalog = benoatsc_GreenFilm");

        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        String totalDonations = string.Empty;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                using (MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select count(*) from films.user where user_name=@username AND password = @password", cs))
                {
                    SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username.Text);
                    SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password.Text);
                    cs.Open();
                    int count = (int)SelectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                    if (count == 1)
                    {
                        Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('wow your in !!');</script>");
                    }
                    else if (count > 1)
                    {
                        Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('duplicate');</script>");
                    }

                    else Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('wrong password');</script>");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert(ex.message);</script>");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Using parameters with command will save you from [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Thank you, but when i try this is tells me username and password.text dose not exist yet i have the text boxes ?

Comment: @Beep, I just copied it from your code *without `this`*, try, `this.username.Text` and `this.password.Text` but I don't think that should have any effect.

Comment: thank you, i have accepted Sudhakar Tillapudi answer but thanks four your help